# File not found error : Unable to access serial port (connected to webcam) in jupyter lab (browser) - in MacOS Monterey

Tags: macos, python, webcam

```
import serial 
from serial.tools import list_ports
from serial import Serial

port = list(list_ports.comports())
for p in port:
    print(p.device)

    ser = serial.Serial(
    # Serial Port to read the data from
    port='/dev/cu.usbserial-110',baudrate = 115200,
    #Applying Parity Checking (none in this case)
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
   # Pattern of Bits to be read
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    # Total number of bits to be read
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    # Number of serial commands to accept before timing out
    timeout=1)
# Pause the program for 1 second to avoid overworking the serial port
while 1:
        x=ser.readline()
        print(x)
```

Output:

```
/dev/cu.wlan-debug
/dev/cu.OnePlusBudsZ
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
```

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py:322, in Serial.open(self)
    321 try:
--> 322     self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    323 except OSError as msg:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/cu.usbserial-110'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SerialException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [34], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 ser = serial.Serial(
      2         # Serial Port to read the data from
      3         port='/dev/cu.usbserial-110',baudrate = 115200,
      4         #Applying Parity Checking (none in this case)
      5         parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
      6        # Pattern of Bits to be read
      7         stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
      8         # Total number of bits to be read
      9         bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
     10         # Number of serial commands to accept before timing out
     11         timeout=1)
     12 # Pause the program for 1 second to avoid overworking the serial port
     13 while 1:

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py:244, in SerialBase.__init__(self, port, baudrate, bytesize, parity, stopbits, timeout, xonxoff, rtscts, write_timeout, dsrdtr, inter_byte_timeout, exclusive, **kwargs)
    241     raise ValueError('unexpected keyword arguments: {!r}'.format(kwargs))
    243 if port is not None:
--> 244     self.open()

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py:325, in Serial.open(self)
    323 except OSError as msg:
    324     self.fd = None
--> 325     raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
    326 #~ fcntl.fcntl(self.fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, 0)  # set blocking
    328 self.pipe_abort_read_r, self.pipe_abort_read_w = None, None

SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/cu.usbserial-110: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/cu.usbserial-110'
```

I wanted to access a webcamera through serial port using python.

Previously, I had done this and the list of ports showed this `/dev/cu.usbserial-110` as one of the ports. Now, when I re-run the program after a month, I am unable to find this port and it shows FileNotFoundError.

I am a beginner in python and need your help.

Comment: Why is there output in the middle of your code? Is that an error whilst writing your question, or is that actually in your code? If the latter, then obviously that is your problem! Also  please paste the error messages as text and not as a screenshot...

Comment: I am using Jupyter lab (so the Output I mentioned  is after executing first cell, followed by the  next cell with its error output).

Comment: Ah, ok. Now it makes sense (a little bit)... although it "is* still really rather confusing way to present your code. In that case, it *might* still be worth including the screenshot (as well as the text form, so as to clarify why you have written the text in the way that you have. I hope that helps.

Comment: Anyway, the reason for your error could be that the device (`cu.serial-110`) in `/dev` no longer exists (whereas it did previously). Run `ls /dev/cu.usbserial-*` in Terminal and check to see if the output includes `cu.serial-110`. Maybe the number has changed. If it has, then change your code appropriately.

Comment: It shows `zsh: no matches found: /dev/cu.usbserial-*`

Comment: I dont understand why I get `/dev/cu.wlan-debug` as one of the ports.

Comment: So, the error is that the device isn't there. Now, why it isn't there, is another matter, which I don't know the answer to. Nor, do I know what `cu.wlan-debug` is... sorry :-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error seems to be that the device (`cu.serial-110`) in `/dev` no longer exists (whereas it did previously).

In Terminal, run

```
ls /dev/cu.usbserial-*
```

Check to see if the output includes `cu-serial-110`. Maybe the device number has changed. If it has, then change your code appropriately.

Also, as a sanity check, make sure that the device is corrctly plugged in to the USB port. Maybe unplug it and then plug it back in - and run the `ls` command again.